# Why am I unable to save an associated object in a has_one relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a pickem object that has one result. I'm having an issue getting the result to save properly to the database.

pickems_controller.rb

```
def results
 @pickem = Pickem.find params[:id]
 # @pickem.result = @pickem.build_result if @pickem.result.blank?
 @pickem.result = Result.new
end

def update_results
 @pickem = Pickem.find params[:id]
 @pickem.result = Result.new params[:pickem][:result_attributes]

 if @pickem.result.update_attributes params[:pickem][:result_attributes]
  redirect_to edit_pickem_results_path(@pickem), :notice => 'The results have been successfully updated.'
 else
  render "edit"
 end
end
```

results.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @pickem, :url => edit_pickem_results_path(@pickem), :method => :put,  do |f| %>

 <%= f.simple_fields_for :result do |r| %>
  <%= r.input :first_name %>
  ...
 <% end %>

 <%= f.submit :class => 'btn btn-success', :label => 'Submit Results' %>

<% end %>
```

pickem.rb

```
has_one :result, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :result
```

result.rb

```
belongs_to :pickem
```

I was initially using the build_result code that is commented out in the controller but had to back out of that. With build_result a result record was saved to the database the instant somebody clicked into the results form. There are rules in place in the application that don't allow users to make any picks if a result has been entered. So even if a user clicked into the result form but didn't submit, the result was still being created.

How can I build my form and save the result record only when the user clicks save, and not when the form is loaded? The current solution I've pasted above does not work. It saves a result record with the appropriate foreign key but never gets the form data. If I dump @pickem.result the correct form data is in the result object, I just can't get it to save right. Other solutions I've tried save the form data correctly but have a foreign key of 0.

EDIT:
For whatever reason `@pickem.result = Result.new` was still saving a record to the database so I changed it to `@result = Result.new` and updated the form as follows:

```
<%= simple_form_for @result, :url => edit_pickem_results_path(@pickem), :method => :put,  do |r| %>

 <%= r.input :first_name %>
 <%= r.submit :class => 'btn btn-success', :label => 'Submit Results' %>

<% end %>
```

Then using the suggestion from Chuck W of `@result = @pickem.result.build params[:result]`, I get `undefined method`build' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: Yep, your change won't work because now your controller isn't receiving a pickem I'd parameter.  I've edited my response below with a possible answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pickems_controller.rb

```
def results
  @pickem = Pickem.find params[:id]
  @pickem.result.blank? ? @result = Result.new : @result = @pickem.result
end


def update_results
  @pickem = Pickem.find params[:id]
  @result = @pickem.result.build params[:pickem][:result]   
  if @result.save
   redirect_to edit_pickem_results_path(@pickem), :notice => 'The results have been successfully updated.'
  else
   render "edit"
  end
end
```

Then, your view should look something like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @pickem, :url => edit_pickem_results_path(@pickem), :method => :put,  do |f| %>

 <%= f.simple_fields_for @result do |r| %>
  <%= r.input :first_name %>
  ...
 <% end %>

 <%= f.submit :class => 'btn btn-success', :label => 'Submit Results' %>

<% end %>
```

You might have to play around with how the parameters are being passed back to the update_results action (I'm pretty new to rails), but I think you get the gist of it.

Comment: For whatever reason a result record is still being created when clicking into the result form. Why would this be? `Result.new` should not be saving.

Comment: Only have this line in your results action: `@pickem = Pickem.find params[:id]`.  Then in your form change: `<%= f.simple_fields_for :result do |r| %>` to `<%= f.simple_fields_for Result.new do |r| %>`

Comment: Hmm, still getting `undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear.  Make my changes to your original view code . . . the code that sets the pickem id param with:  <%= simple_form_for @pickem, :url => edit_pickem_results_path(@pickem), :method => :put,  do |f| %>

Comment: I did :) I modified update_results to @result = @pickem.build_result params[:pickem][:result] and it saves the record to the database correctly. However, when opening the form up it just loads an empty form since I'm calling `f.simple_fields_for Result.new `.

Comment: I guess another question I have is why does `@pickem.result = Result.new` save an empty record to the database? I'm just calling new, not create or save. If it didn't save I could theoretically do something like `@pickem.result = Result.new if @pickem.result.blank?`

Comment: Ahhh.  Now I see what you're trying to do.  From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), _"Assigning an object to a has_one association automatically saves that object and the object being replaced (if there is one), in order to update their foreign keys - except if the parent object is unsaved (new_record? == true)."_  I've updated my answer to provide the functionality that you're looking for.

Comment: Yes! That is perfect. And looking at it now, it seems so simple. Thanks for the info from the docs, that explains exactly what my problem was. And thanks for sticking with this issue!